# Implementing a interface from dynamically loaded jar file using dexloader

Tags: android

I am working on a project in which i have to load a jar file from SD card at run-time.I have successfully achieved this using `dexloader` class and also i am able to invoke any function with or without arguments of a class in jar file.

Now the challenge i am facing is that i have to implement a interface that is present in jar file for callbacks in my project.I am unable to find any solution to achieve this till now.

I am invoking a method this way:

```
   final Class[] args = new Class[1];
   args[0] = Context.class;
   final Method doSomething = classToLoad.getMethod("doSomething",    args);
   final Object myInstance = classToLoad.newInstance();
   doSomething.invoke(myInstance, this);
```

where classLoad is a instance of class loaded dynamically from jar file.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Proxy.newProxyInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E[],%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29) to create a proxy object that will implement a given interface(s). The calls to the interface methods are handled by your [InvocationHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html).
Example:
Your interface loaded dynamically:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
   void doSomething(Context context);
}
```

Create an object implementing SomeInterface

```
Class[] ia = new Class[1];
ia[0] = Class.forName("SomeInterface");
handler = new MyHandler();
Object obj = Proxy.newProxyInstance(context.getClassLoader(),ia,handler)
```

Class MyHandler will handle calls to SomeInterface methods:

```
class MyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
  public Object invoke (Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
      if(method.getName().equals("doSomething")) {
         Context context = (Context)args[0];
         // do something here
      }
      return null; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Its not clear.How you will access that interface..?? and will it return a callback to project.??

Comment: newProxyInstance() returns an object that implements the desired interface. When an interface method is called on that object, the call is forwarded to the InvocationHandler instance given to newProxyInstance().

Comment: Please see my edited question i have added a part of my code.Can you please help how and where to implement your solution... :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for it...i have a doubt that where i will do further functionality using the proxy in my handler class or obj in above code.. :) and how we will override the interface's method dosomething in current code